what is the following identity called that involves Laguerre Polynomial?
It seems that (I tested with Mathematica for a few $m_1$ and $m_2$) the following identity hold, where $m_1, m_2$ are positive integers. Is this true? If it is true, what is called in the literature?
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n_1=0} \frac{x^{n_1}}{n_1!}L(m_1,-m_1+n_1,x) L(m_3,-m_3+n_1,x)=\frac{e^{x}x^{m_1}}{m_1!}\delta_{m_1,m_3}$$
I don't know what this property is called in literature. It doesn't look like the orthogonality, since that involves the integration over $x$. But this also look like some sort of orthogonality relation.

What is your definition of $L(\alpha, \beta, x)$?
